# Recibir valor de un input y mostrarlo sin que se actualice la pagina

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, estoy recibiendo un valor de un input y lo estoy mostrando, el problema es que cada vez que hago la consulta se actualiza la pagina y no quiero que se actualice la pagina cada vez que hago dicha consulta, que podria hacer?

```
 <form action="" class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                <label for="">Monto a tomar</label>
                <input id="inputFuerte" type="number">
                <br>
                <button id="boton">Convertir</button>
                <br>
                <label for="">Monto a mostrar</label>
                <div id="txt"></div>
            </form>
```

Javascript

```
        //BsF    
    var montoRecibido = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").value;
   //Bs.S
   var montoMostrar = document.getElementById("inputSoberano");
   //boton
    var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
   //funcion
   function recibir(){
    bsF = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").value;  
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=bsF;
   }

   boton.addEventListener("click", recibir);
```

Answer (score 2):

A menos que vayas a enviar información al servidor, las etiquetas `<form>` y `</form>` no son necesarias, puedes hacerlo perfectamente sin ellas.

```js
       //BsF    
    var montoRecibido = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").value;
   //Bs.S
   var montoMostrar = document.getElementById("inputSoberano");
   //boton
    var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
   //funcion
   function recibir(){
    bsF = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").value;  
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=bsF;
   }

   boton.addEventListener("click", recibir);
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
    <label for="">Monto a tomar</label>
    <input id="inputFuerte" type="number">
    <br>
    <button id="boton">Convertir</button>
    <br>
    <label for="">Monto a mostrar</label>
    <div id="txt"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

primero hay una variable que estas creando apartir de un elemento que no tienes en el html, que es la variable montoMostrar, llamas por id a inputsoberano pero no hay nada que se llame asi.
segundo, para lo que intentas hacer prueba poniendo:

```js
   //BsF    
var montoRecibido = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").valueAsNumber;
//Bs.S
var montoMostrar = document.getElementById("inputSoberano");
//boton
 var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
//funcion
function recibir(e){

// esto previene que la pagina se recargue
e.preventDefault();
//


bsF = document.getElementById("inputFuerte").value;  
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML= bsF;
}

boton.addEventListener("click", recibir);
```

```html
 <form action="" class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                <label for="">Monto a tomar</label>
                <input id="inputFuerte" type="number">
                <br>
                <button id="boton">Convertir</button>
                <br>
                <label for="">Monto a mostrar</label>
                <div id="txt"></div>
            </form>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```